# Power BI Drill Through on multiple rows

Tags: powerbi-desktop, drillthrough

I have a table with a category that currently drills through to a home page. I was wondering if there was any way to select multiple categories on this list then drill through with that selection. Ctrl left clicking then right clicking does not allow you to drill through. Is there any way to accomplish this? Thank you for your help!